# Host write guarantees source access scope

Tags: vulkan

According to the spec (1.2.138), section 6.9 (Host Write Ordering Guarantees):

> When batches of command buffers are submitted to a queue via vkQueueSubmit, it defines a
>   memory dependency with prior host operations, and execution of command buffers submitted to
>   the queue.

[...]

> The first access scope includes all host writes to mappable device memory that are available to the
>   host memory domain.

does "mappable" mean allocated using `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT`?

does "available to the host memory domain" mean **currently mapped**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does "mappable" mean allocated using `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT`?

Yes.

> does "available to the host memory domain" mean currently mapped?

No.

On device that means synchronization that includes Domain Op to the host is performed. That means barrier-like primitive with `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT`.

Or on host writes via the mapped pointer have to be `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges` if they are not `COHERENT`. The memory write is already in host domain, but `vkFlush` performs the Availability OP.

In this chapter it means the later. Memory writes through the mapped pointer that are `COHERENT` or `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges` will automatically\implicitly get to be visible to the GPU on the next `vkQueueSubmit`.